# Integral of probability density less than one

Tags: probability-theory

If $X_{n}$ is a sequence of random variables with densities $f_{n}$ converging pointwise to $f$, is it possible for $\int_{R}fd\lambda<1$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For instance the density for an exponential with mean $1/n$, which is given by $f_n(x)=ne^{-nx}$ (with support $x>0$), converges pointwise to zero.

Answer (score 0):

A even simpler example is $f_n(x)=n1_{(0,\frac{1}{n}]}\left(x\right)$ that converges point wise to $f\equiv 0$.